# MongoDb driver is not inserting the entire object

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am having some trouble while inserting object into MongoDb in C#. My code is just like this:

```
_db.GetCollection<LogRecord> (collectionName).InsertOneAsync (log);
```

The object that I'm trying to insert is just like this:

[image]

When I check in my collection, Status object is always missing:

[image: My mongoDb object]

My object:

```
public class LogRecord
{
    public Dictionary<string, QueryDetailsRecord>   QueryDetails         { get; set; }
}

public class QueryDetailsRecord
{
    public double       ElapsedTime      { get; set; }
    public bool         InfoFound        { get; set; }

    // Cache vars
    public int          CacheValidDays   { get; set; }
    public bool         CacheEnabled     { get; set; }
    public bool         CacheUsed        { get; set; }

    // Errors codes        
    public StatusRecord Status           { get; set; }
    public string       ExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public QueryDetailsRecord() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elapsedTime">Elapsed time</param>
    /// <param name="status">Status object</param>        
    /// <param name="exceptionMessage">Error message</param>
    public QueryDetailsRecord (double elapsedTime, StatusRecord status, string exceptionMessage)
    {
        ElapsedTime      = elapsedTime;
        Status           = status;            
        ExceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
    }
}

public class StatusRecord
{
    private int    _code = -1;
    private string _msg  = null;

    public int Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return _msg; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">Status code</param>
    /// <param name="msg">Status message</param>
    public StatusRecord (int code, string msg)
    {
        _code = code;
        _msg  = msg;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue of what's happing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show definition of `LogRecord` class?

Comment: I guess that your QueryDetailsRecord has some attributes applied, or that you configured some serializers, leading to the field being ignored. Or StatusRecord is a struct. Read [ask] and show all relevant code.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy updated with the object =)

Comment: @CodeCaster there is no attribute applied actually. I updated with the entire object =)

Comment: Going to take a swing ;p is it maybe that it does not know how to use the Constructor? and would prefer to use the Properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue a few days ago. 
Maybe it's happening because the properties "**code**" and "**message**" defined on your "**Status**" Dictionary are private, this way the method "InsertOneAsync" cannot "see" them.

Try to define "**code**" and "**message**" as **public** and see if it works.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks bro!